# How does one instantiate an EasyScoreCalculator for an Optaplanner Solver?

Tags: optaplanner

The [OptaPlanner documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.6.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#scoreCalculationTypes) lists the following example code:

> Alternatively, build a EasyScoreCalculator instance at runtime and set it with the programmatic API:
>
> ```
> solverFactory.getSolverConfig().getScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setEasyScoreCalculator(easyScoreCalculator);
> ```

I assume that is intended to be: (missing function call)

```
solverFactory.getSolverConfig().getScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().setEasyScoreCalculator(easyScoreCalculator);
```

However, [the JavaDoc describes](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.7.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/config/score/director/ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.html) no way to set an instantiated `EasyScoreCalculator`, only a way to specify a class. I'd like to vary some parameters at run-time and constructing an `EasyScoreCalculator` seems to me to be a reasonable way to do this. It seems like it is intended to be supported, but it really isn't.

How should I vary parameters for my score calculator between solver runs at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`setEasyScoreCalculator()` is intentionally not available**, because in multi-threaded solving as well is in other use cases (such as "explaining the score" - see docs), there will be multiple EasyScoreCalculator instances active in parallel, so we need to be able to instantiate them.

> How should I vary parameters for my score calculator between solver
>   runs at run-time?

A `<customPhase>` element (see `CustomPhaseConfig.java`) supports `Map<String, String> customProperties` to vary parameters of a custom phase. `PartitionedSearchPhaseConfig.java` supports this aspect too, in a similar manner for other functionality. *Create an issue in our issue tracker (see "get help" on optaplanner.org) to support this on EasyScoreCalculator, IncrementalScoreCalculator and Drools too.* For Drools it would inject those properties into global fields.

It should be fairly straightforward to implement in a pull request. Add such a Map in ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java, pass it to the ScoreDirectorFactory who calls ConfigUtils to set it on the calculator instance.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the rationale there to be able to construct multiple instances. Would you object to a PR that instead allows supplying a `Supplier<EasyScoreCalculator>` or that requests a `Cloneable` `EasyScoreCalculator` instead of via a reference to the class.

Comment: [I wrote up a PR to illustrate what I mean](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/386). It's a little ugly to preserve backwards compatibility around the `easyScoreCalculatorClass`.